# "python manage.py runserver" = cannot execute binary file error (django)

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

new one to me
commend
I'm running ubuntu 10.04 relatively fresh install on my laptop
manually installed django 1.2.1

when I try to run inside of a virtualenv

```
python manage.py **any command**
```

I get the error "bash: /home/alvin/workspace/storm-guard/virtual_damage_restoration/bin/python: cannot execute binary file
"

I have done the following so far:

- removed and re-installed django
- removed and re-installed project directory
- removed first line from manage.py that defines the python shell to use
- verified file has permission to execute
- re-installed virtualenv

at this point I'm scratching my head

any advice is greatly apreciated

Comment: further testing has shown that any file inside the virtualenv provides the same error - any ideas?

Comment: Does the vm use the same binary format as your host machine?

Answer (score 0):

the virtualenv I was attempting to use was copied from another computer

for whatever reason when I created a new virtualenv and copied the bin directory over the existing everything started working

Comment: Yeah, virtualenv sets up sym links to your python binaries.  When you copy from another computer, they aren't necessarily valid anymore (for example, the other computer might have a different version of python installed).  Even copying to a different location on the same machine can be problematic unless you use the --relocatable flag.